# Nested Gamma functions and $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, convergence-divergence, gamma-function

Hi it's a problem that I cannot prove :

> > Let $1\leq a_0\leq 3$ and defines the following sequence :
> >     $$\Gamma(a_n)=a_{n+1}$$
> >     Where $\Gamma(x)$ is the Gamma function and $n\geq 0$ a natural number.
> >
> > Then : $$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=1$$

I think we can consider two cases when $1\leq a_0\leq 2$ and $2\leq a_0\leq 3$

I have tried to use the approximated [inverse Gamma function](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12828/inverse-gamma-function) without success . 
Furthermore on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gautschi%27s_inequality) we have (result  due to Kečkić and Vasić) :

$$x^{x-1}e^{1-x}<\Gamma(x)<x^{x-\frac{1}{2}}e^{1-x}$$
Where $x>1$

So if we define for $1\leq b_0\leq 2$ the following sequence :

$$b_{n+1}=b_n^{b_n-\frac{1}{2}}e^{1-b_n}$$

We see numerically that it tends to one .

But it doesn't work so well with the LHS , the $b_n$ looks complicated and we lost the initial inequality .

I have not try an experimentation with the integral definition of the Gamma function .

I think it's a hard nut so if you have just an approach to begin.

Any helps is greatly appreciated .

Thanks a lot for your contributions

Comment: Maybe note that $$\Gamma(x)\lt x$$for $x\in(1,3]$ so the limit exists and is equal to $1$ by the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: Yes it's simple since the inequality implies that $a_{n+1}< a_n$ so it's decreasing and it tends to $\Gamma(1)=1$ by the theorem you mention .Thanks !!